# asp.net contentpage automatically adding div

Tags: asp.net

I placed a dropdownlist in the content placeholder entitled cpmainwrapper . I then placed a detailsview congtrol beneath it and wanted to use float:left to have them render side by side.
After failing, I checked the code on the browser and see that the detailsview is being placed in its own div. 
How can I make them show side by side?

Comment: Easier to help you if you show the code, but it sounds to me like you could achieve that with CSS.

Comment: Does the page have the DIV in the markup? In Visual Studio when you use "Add New WebForm" dialog, by default it adds a Div to page markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the css float on the DetailsView as well as the DropDownList.

Either in the head of your page markup or in a seperate CSS include file;

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ddlStyle
  {
    float: left;
  }
  .dvStyle 
  {
    float: left;
  }
</style>
```

And (although greatly simplified) in your ASPX page;

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" CssClass="ddlStyle" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="dv1" CssClass="dvStyle" runat="server">
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Depending on the browser(s) you are targetting you could consider using inline-block instead of float on the DetailsView;

```
.dvStyle 
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you are targetting multiple browsers, it would be prudent of me to warn you to test the CSS across browsers and note that IE can do strange things with floats:
[What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Comment: Don't know what changed. It starting to work on it's own. Thanks for suggestions.